# how to continue pulling data from a server like binance?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, algorithmic-trading

I am trading on binance, I have a code that pulling data for 5 minutes candle (for example), when I click on run code, it will collect data, but how to continue pulling also for new candles ? this is my code:

```
import binance.client
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import time 
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Pkey = 'xxxxxxxx'
Skey = 'ccccccccccccc'

client = Client(api_key=Pkey, api_secret=Skey)

ticker = 'BTCUSDT'
interval = Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE
depth = '13 hours ago'

raw = client.get_historical_klines(ticker, interval, depth)
raw = pd.DataFrame(raw)
print(raw)
```

thanks

Comment: Wait for a few seconds and re-execute the same code?

Answer (score 1):

As @Selcuk mentioned is his comment, you can loop the binance read and pause between each read. In your case, you are retrieving data at 5 minute intervals, so you can wait 5 minutes before reading again and request the previous 5 minutes. You can append to the initial dataframe using `append`.

Try this code:

```
import ......

Pkey = 'xxxxxxxx'
Skey = 'ccccccccccccc'

client = Client(api_key=Pkey, api_secret=Skey)

ticker = 'BTCUSDT'
interval = Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE
depth = '13 hours ago'

raw = client.get_historical_klines(ticker, interval, depth)
raw = pd.DataFrame(raw)
alldata = raw
print(raw)  # intial load

depth = '5 minutes ago'
while True:  # loop forever
    time.sleep(300)  # wait 5 minutes
    raw = client.get_historical_klines(ticker, interval, depth)  # 5 minutes of data
    raw = pd.DataFrame(raw)
    alldata.append(raw)  # add to main dataset
```

Comment: Thanks, your code look great, Sorry I am begginer with coding, is this code will loop just for 1 hour ? I need it to go forever. Thanks

Comment: bro thanks for your effort, my data is 35 rows, I run the code, but there is no new row every 5  minutes, please check this image, you can see my code and output https://ibb.co/6mNMkb6

Comment: I tried something like this, it works,
 ''' 
import time ,,
print("hi") ,,
time.sleep(10) #seconds ,,
print("sleep")
'''